# Why does JSON say the serialisation hook is missing?

Tags: json, perl, dbix-class

Run `cpanm --look DBIx::Class ; cd examples/Schema/` to use the example database.

```
use 5.024;
use strictures;
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json);
use MyApp::Schema qw();
use Sub::Install qw();

my $s = MyApp::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:db/example.db');
# Yes, I know Helper::Row::ToJSON exists.
Sub::Install::install_sub({
    code => sub {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return { map {$_ => $self->$_} keys %{ $self->columns_info } };
    },
    into => $s->source('Track')->result_class,
    as   => 'TO_JSON',
});

my ($t) = $s->resultset('Cd')->first->tracks;
say ref $t->can('TO_JSON'); # 'CODE', ok
say ref $t->TO_JSON;        # 'HASH', ok
say encode_json $t;
# encountered object 'MyApp::Schema::Result::Track=HASH(0x1a53b48)',
# but neither allow_blessed, convert_blessed nor allow_tags settings
# are enabled (or TO_JSON/FREEZE method missing) at …
```

I expect the serialiser to find the installed hook and use it, but instead I get the error above. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make `JSON::XS` consider `TO_JSON`, you have to explicitly enable `convert_blessed` option:

```
my $coder = JSON::XS->new;
$coder->convert_blessed(1);
say $coder->encode($t);
```

According to [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.03/XS.pm):

> ```
> $json = $json->convert_blessed ([$enable])
> $enabled = $json->get_convert_blessed
> ```
>
> See "OBJECT SERIALISATION" for details.
>
> If $enable is true (or missing), then encode, upon encountering a blessed object, will check for the availability of the TO_JSON method
>   on the object's class. If found, it will be called in scalar context
>   and the resulting scalar will be encoded instead of the object.
>
> The TO_JSON method may safely call die if it wants. If TO_JSON returns other blessed objects, those will be handled in the same way.
>   TO_JSON must take care of not causing an endless recursion cycle (==
>   crash) in this case. The name of TO_JSON was chosen because other
>   methods called by the Perl core (== not by the user of the object) are
>   usually in upper case letters and to avoid collisions with any to_json
>   function or method.
>
> If **$enable is false (the default)**, then **encode will not consider** this type of conversion.
>
> This setting has no effect on decode.

(emphasis mine)